# How to prove that any two real finite dimensional vector spaces with the same dimension are isomorphic to one another?

Tags: linear-algebra

As the title says: Prove that any two real finite dimensional vector spaces with the same dimension are isomorphic to one another?

How would you approach this proof?

Comment: Actually, this may be a better dupe:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025926/vector-spaces-of-the-same-finite-dimension-are-isomorphic?rq=1  There are likely other dupes, too.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Choose a basis for each. Since you know the dimension you know how many vectors there are in a basis,